# Error in blackberry [ VMDisconnected Error !!! ]

Tags: exception, blackberry, virtual-machine, recordstore, vmdisconnectedexception

I am getting an error in eclipse bb as com.sun.jdi.VMDisconnectedException : Got iOException from Virtual machine

I am trying to store a string in record store which is about 83k characters

The definition gets passed into the function but instantly it gives unknown value after a splits second and then the error why does this happen ?

[image: Error as seen in Eclipse]

Comment: Does it happen when you store a record that is less than 64 KB?  I have a memory of a 64 KB size limit.

Comment: I had to store 3 strings... 2 were relatively smaller which worked... and the 3rd one is about 84k characters which causes error...

Comment: I did put the code in try catch braces and I got UTFDataFormat Exception

Comment: And do you get the same exception if you shorten the 3rd one?  My point here is that if you can't store more than 64 KB in one chunk, you are going to have to split it into two to store it, so you should test this.  Also, why not use another form of persistence, like FileConnection or PersistentStore?

Comment: Isnt there ny other solution.. becoz this means will need to change whole architecture

Comment: I am getting confused by this question.  I think you should update it and provide additional information and clarification.  Are you using the RecordStore API?  You appear to be doing File I/O which suggests FileConnection API rather than RecordStore.  You indicate you get a UTFDataFormatException - have you researched that to confirm whether or not your data was in fact badly formatted?  Who created this data?  So please review your question, think about all the information you might need to give a colleague to resolve this - and give us that.